# How to order by multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I need help ordering my results, probably with a combination of case statements. Please see image showing existing output, conditions, desired output. Exhibited in Excel for ease, but actually done in SQL. The ORDER BY clause is what I need help on.

[image]

```
select 
distinct 
CONCAT(selection.Selid,' - ' ,Selection.Name,' - ', DevOfficer.Description,' - ', SchemeCount.[Number of Schemes],' Schemes - ',case when selection.Project=1 then '[Project] ' when selection.Project=0 then '[Selection] '  else 'Error' end,convert(varchar,selection.lastupdated,103)) [String]
, selection.selid
, selection.lastupdated 
,case when selection.Project=1 then '[Project]'
when selection.Project=0 then '[Selection]'
else 'Error' end
,selection.lastupdated
from selection 
inner join SelScheme on selection.SelID =selscheme.SelID 
inner join DevOfficer on selection.DevOfficer = DevOfficer.DevOfficerID 
inner join (select selscheme.selid ,count(selscheme.SchemeID) [Number of Schemes] from SelScheme group by SelScheme.SelID) SchemeCount on schemecount.SelID = Selection.SelID 
where selection.masterselid = 0 
order by 
--selection.lastupdated  desc,
case 
when selection.Project=1 then '[Project]'
when selection.Project=0 then '[Selection]' 
 else 'Error' End Desc
 ,selid desc
 ,selection.lastupdated
```

Comment: Tables and code should be submitted as text

Comment: It looks like you will indeed need some case when order by statements. `ORDER BY Type, CASE WHEN other conditions THEN the next field to order by and so on...`

Comment: Can you provide tables and data as text from sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the order by you need:

```
order by type desc,
         id desc, 
         case when isdate(last_updated_date) then last_updated_date else 0 end desc
```

use asc and desc modifiers, for each order-by column you need

Comment: This will still order the projects by ID first. I want to order the projects by lastupdated desc, and am not concerned about the order of the their IDs

Comment: If I put ID after the case statement, it works. That is, order by type, ID, lastupdated.

It works because there are no lastupdated dates for selections.

Answer (score 0):

*** Answered before code snippet added to OP question***

Although I'm unsure of SQL table name and even the actual SQL field names, the below will work.
You need to list all fields in the ORDER BY based on their priority;

```
     SELECT
     [ID]
    ,[Type]
    ,[Last Updated Date]
    FROM [SCHEMA].[TABLENAME]
    ORDER BY [Type] ASC, [ID] DESC, [Last Updated Date] DESC
```

Comment: This will still order projects by ID first and then Lastupdated but what I need is Type, then by ID if Selection, but by date if Project.

Comment: This will order by [Type] first. '01.' comes before '02.' which is why it is ascending order

Comment: Sorry, I meant before, not first.